# Phonegap app can not connect to database on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, phonegap

I have been been working on an app in phonegap and make login and register with JavaScript and ajax call.

So I tested it on Google Chrome and it works perfect, connecting on server (mysql) and inserting data etc... So I decide to build app to test it on mobile (android), and it just not responding when I click on register or login button. 
Is there some code or file which I need to import ?

Comment: What is your database host you are trying to connect to? Is it localhost because you can't connect to that from your phone? Is the database accessible from the phone?

Comment: @Loren It is server where I have website...

Comment: If you post your database connection code (minus the username/password of course) and the register/login call, that would help us help better.

Comment: @Loren So on mobile phone, after click on Login or Register button, it has been stopped here: `beforeSend: function(){
 $("#login").val('Connecting...');
 },`

Comment: I need the entire AJAX function call to be able to help, please edit your question so you can post the full code.

Comment: @Loren Well, problem was in config.xml file, where I should enable some plugins and intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application did not receive internet connection, so I changed my config.xml file.
Core plugins I found here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

Answer (score 1):

Check the url you are connecting with in the ajax call, if its a full path